# How to show a clock on a wpf form which shows h:m:s and updating every second?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I want to show a clock on a wpf window, the clock should show the time passed from the moment when I click a button on the same form beginning from 00:00:00 and updating once a second. When some even occurs, it should stop without reset and when I click the button again it should reset and begin counting the time again.

What's an approach to accomplish this? Should I use a simple label? 
In my app I use async and await for other things, what should I use for the clock and how do I run a method which "handler" I can use for updating the clock once a second?

Comment: Far too broad. Please **try something** first. You should follow the normal WPF paradigms: create a timer that updates e.g. a `TimeSpan` or `DateTime` value, and then bind that something that displays it in your window. If you have a _specific_ problem doing that, provide a good [mcve] showing clearly what you've tried with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: Please post )i.e., code) your attempt at solving the problem and ask us specifically as to what is not working.

Answer (score -1):

Use a StopWatch. The code below will get you started.

```
Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
DispatcherTimer timer;
private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!w.IsRunning)
    {
        w.Start();

        if (timer == null )
        {
            timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        }
        timer.Start();
    }
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (w.IsRunning)
    {                
        TbClock.Text = w.Elapsed.Hours + ":" + w.Elapsed.Minutes + ":" + w.Elapsed.Seconds;
        Debug.WriteLine(w.Elapsed.Hours + ":" + w.Elapsed.Minutes + ":" + w.Elapsed.Seconds);
    }
}

private void BtnEnd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (w.IsRunning)
    {              
        w.Stop();
        w.Reset();

        timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: For a WPF program, the above is surprisingly lacking in XAML and use of data binding.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Add unnecessary complexity by bringing DPs to show hours/minutes/seconds when simple approach is enough. TbClock in above code is TextBlock. SO is not for spoon feeding. For any sensible person, hint is enough. Make such a clock using XAML, and post your code here.

Comment: Why to use both StopWatch and Timer, why not only Timer?