# A way to get the number of milliseconds in real time passed since the last call of a method

Tags: c#, wpf, timing

I'm calling an update function to draw a real time simulation and was wondering if there was an effective way to get the number of milliseconds passed since the last update? At the moment I have a DispatchTimer calling at regular intervals to update the simulation but the timing isn't accurate enough and ends up being about 60% slower than it should be (it varies).

Comment: Try `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch`.

Comment: I wrote a Clock in this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967369/how-to-show-a-clock-on-a-wpf-form-which-shows-hms-and-updating-every-second/33967889#33967889

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()` to get a tick count, then compare the value before and after.  You can convert this to timings by:

```
var startTicks = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
// Do stuff
var ticks = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() - startTicks;

double seconds = ticks / Stopwatch.Frequency;
double milliseconds = (ticks / Stopwatch.Frequency) * 1000;
double nanoseconds = (ticks / Stopwatch.Frequency) * 1000000000;
```

You could also use `var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();` and `sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds` afterwards if you just want to time different chunks of code.

Comment: Thank you this worked quite well, used stopwatch.ElapsedTicks to measure tick count.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a variable that will not reset between calls.
Yours may not need to be static like mine.

```
private static DateTime _LastLogTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Then within the method:

```
// This ensures only the exact one Tick is used for subsequent calculations
// Instead of calling DateTime.Now again and getting different values
DateTime NewTime = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan ElapsedTime = NewTime - _LastLogTime;
_LastLogTime = NewTime;

string LogMessage = string.Format("{0,7:###.000}", ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds);
```

I only needed down to the thousandth of a second within my string, but you can get much more accurate with the resulting TimeSpan.

Also there is a `.TotalMilliseconds` or even `.Ticks`(*the most accurate*) value available within the resulting TimeSpan.

Comment: I would recommend using `DateTime.UtcNow` for these sorts of purposes else you will get spurious results across clock changes.